# How to convert IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue> > to IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue> >?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, ienumerable

I have a function that return a `IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue> >`.
I have another function that takes a `IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue> >`.

I need to pass the return of the first function to the second function.
The compiler doesn't want to implicitlty convert the first into the second. So how could I convert the first into the second in O(1)?

I could always write a conversion function

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> ToIEnumerable<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> source)
{
    return source.ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value.AsEnumerable());
}
```

But I'm pretty sure this is not O(1), more like O(log n).

A related question here : [Nested Interfaces: Cast IDictionary< TKey, IList< TValue > > to IDictionary< TKey, IEnumerable < TValue> >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399568/nested-interfaces-cast-idictionarytkey-ilisttvalue-to-idictionarytkey-ie?rq=1)

Comment: Just curious, what's purpose you want to do this?

Comment: Hum, be able to call my second function without losing time by doing a conversion which seems not necessary!

Comment: If you want O(1). Just write a wrapper around it. I dont see the issue though `List<T>` is already `IEnumerable<T>`. Where is the conversion?

Comment: It's not so much a related question as the *same* question, right?

Comment: @AakashM, the devil is in the details. I don't need to cast my dictionary, it is more a conversion in O(1)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your second function, the one that

```
 takes a IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue> >
```

Now, if you give me a `IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>`, one of the things I should be able to do is set the value of one of the keys to a `new TValue[]`, right? After all, a `TValue[]` is an `IEnumerable<TValue>`, so it meets the constraint.

However, if somehow what you'd given me was (underneath the interface) a `IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`, I definitely *shouldn't* be allowed to set the value of a key to a `TValue[]`, since a `TValue[]` is not a `List<TValue>`!

This is exactly the problem in the question you have linked, of course.

Now, if you are happy to only ever **read** the parameter I pass you, you have a potential solution in moving from dictionaries to [`ILookup<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx), which is a bit like a *read-only* dictionary from a key to a *list* of values. If your methods respectively return and accept an `ILookup<TKey, TValue>` there's of course no problem.

Comment: ILookup is a nice solution. Too bad it doesn't support empty list.

Comment: @Scorpi0 is that a problem, given that when you look up a key, ["If the key is not found in the collection, an empty sequence is returned"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292716.aspx) ?

Comment: Not really. I have some logic based on the keys present in the dictionary. So if the key doesn't exist, well, I can't retrieve it easily. Side question : I can't install framework 4.5, but is the [ReadOnlyDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875.aspx) could do the trick? I can't test it.

Comment: @Scorpi0 I only gave that link as it is the canonical doc link, which goes to the most recent version. The Other Versions dropdown shows it's been present since .NET 3.5 (~= VS 2008). I suspect `ReadOnlyDictionary` might not be so easy to work with, but I haven't checked.